# How to auto select checkbox by checking all password credentials(i.e one uppercase,one lowercase and so on) using Text Watcher in single Edit text?

Tags: android, textwatcher

One edit text is there for password there i enter text inside edit text then below i have four check box one checkbox for password containing A-Z second one for containing a-z third for 0-9 this way so while i enter password it will auto check e.g In my password i have entered Uppercase letter so first checkbox gets auto select and so on.But its working for only first letter i.e checkbox is selected but for second letter that i enter its not working

Here is my code:

```
pwd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkfeedback1);
        CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkfeedback2);
        CheckBox checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkfeedback3);
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
            String str=pwd.getText().toString();
            if (str.length()>0 && str.length()<5) {
                if (isValidPassword(pwd.getText().toString()).equals("first")) {
                    checkBox1.setChecked(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password is valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    checkBox1.setChecked(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone number or Password is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (isValidPassword(pwd.getText().toString()).equals("second")) {
                    checkBox2.setChecked(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password is valid for second checkbox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    checkBox3.setChecked(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone number or Password is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (isValidPassword(pwd.getText().toString()).equals("third")) {
                    checkBox3.setChecked(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password is valid for third checkbox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    checkBox3.setChecked(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone number or Password is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
private String isValidPassword(String passwrd) {
    boolean check = false;
    if (Pattern.matches("[A-Z]+", passwrd)) {
        check = true;
        return "first";

    }
    if(Pattern.matches("[a-z]+", passwrd))
    {
        check = true;
        return "second";

    }
    if(Pattern.matches("[0-9]+", passwrd))
    {
        check = true;
        return "third";

    }
    else
    {
        check = false;

    }
    return "check";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some hint for you

**1** Don't use `pwd.getText().toString()` in `addTextChangedListener` instead of that use `s` like below code

**2** Don't initialize you CheckBoxs in `addTextChangedListener` instead of that initialize in `onCreate()`

**3** Use different method for validation

**4** Don't use checkbox1,checkbox2,... instead use checkboxLower,checkboxUpper,...

So your code must like this

```
   pws.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            checkBoxLower.setChecked(hasLowerCase(charSequence.toString()));
            checkBoxUpper.setChecked(hasUpperCase(charSequence.toString()));
            checkBoxNumber.setChecked(hasNumber(charSequence.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }

        private boolean hasLowerCase(String s){
            return !s.equals(s.toUpperCase());
        }

        private boolean hasUpperCase(String s){
            return !s.equals(s.toLowerCase());
        }

        private boolean hasNumber(String s){
            return s.matches(".*\\d+.*");
        }

    });
```

Comment: did you change all pwd.getText().toString() to s   ?

Comment: I have tried this way now but still its not working onTextChanged() is called only once for first letter in edit text its not working for second letter in the same edit text.

Comment: String str=s.toString();
                if (str.length()>0 && str.length()<5) {
                    if (isValidPassword(pwd.getText().toString()).equals("first")) {
                        checkBox1.setChecked(true);

Comment: One edit text is there for password there i enter text inside edit text then below i have four check box one checkbox for password containing A-Z second one for containing a-z third for 0-9 this way so while i enter password it will auto check e.g In my password i have entered Uppercase letter so first checkbox gets auto select and so on.But its working for only first letter i.e checkbox is selected but for second letter that i enter its not working.

Comment: @pratival I write new code for you use this method for your purpose. check my edited code

Comment: I tried your code its working fine now i got the solution.Thank You